# Upload my php project files to use with google cloud AppEngine

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I've spent 10+ hours yesterday reading up about / testing tutorials with google cloud and how I can use them as a host for my dynamic website.

With all of the new information in my head, I'm scrambled on what to do.

I already have my Virtual Machine Instance built with an IP that links to my domain, this works fine. However, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to put my project files on there. I figured it would have been something like "upload project files", "link with appengine", "link with cloud sql", but it seems like I was wrong?

In the tutorials, I uploaded googles sample projects (tutorials) by cloning a github link in the shell.

```
git clone https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-php.git
```

They also said a zip file could be extracted as an alternative.

Are those the only way of doing this? Should I create my own github and cone it in the shell?

Is it possible to link an AppEngine with a bucket that has my project files on there? (just throwing the question out there)

**bonus question:** once the files are uploaded, am I able to edit/develop through google cloud or do I need to edit changes in my files, then re-upload it to the cloud as an update?

This is my first time trying to have google (or any company) host my website, and this is completely foreign territory for me so any direction is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there are couple things mixed up in your question. Let me try to untangle them.

1. You don't need to create virtual machine if you want to run your PHP powered website on App Engine. There's a great overview in this article https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/an-overview-of-app-engine
2. The way you run your PHP website on App Engine is by deploying your code to the version, you can do it using `gcloud app deploy` tool from your sources on your local machine. I recommend you to start by going through tutorial on here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/quickstart
3. There's currently no way to link Google Cloud Storage bucket with App Engine version, you have to deploy your code yourself using either `gloud app deploy` or using App Engine Admin API that gcloud is using internally.
4. There's no way to edit your App Engine application code in the cloud.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's definitely cleared some things up so far.

If possible, could you please elaborate on what you said [2] "you can do it using gcloud app deploy tool from your sources on your local machine." What does this look like? Is there a command I have to enter to define a file path of what to deploy?

Comment: In the tutorial (also mentioned in my question), they have a github clone type command, this is the method I should use to delpoy my files in there?

Comment: In the tutorial I've mentioned in [2] there's a section about downloading SDK, gcloud is part of that sdk. I recommend you to go through tutorial and actually finish all the steps.

Comment: I believe you are talking about this tutorial? https://cloud.google.com/php/getting-started/tutorial-app

It goes through similar process as the quickstart, but deployes your application to App Engine Flexible environment (and also guides you through other things as well). 

I think that confusing part is that you can run your application on multiple different environments on Google Cloud Platform: App Engine Standard, App Engine Flexible, Container Engine, Compute Engine. Each of them is suitable for different purposes.

Comment: I've set up the SDK already, sorry for the confusion, i'm actually referring to the 1st step in "download the hello world app" here https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/quickstart (one of the links you've provided)

I have the SDK downloaded, i've in fact already completed this tutorial yesterday just fine with everything working. The only part I couldn't understand is how to deploy my own files with my own version of this code in the shell:

"git clone https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-php.git"

Comment: I'm just going to start playing with shell commands and see what I can learn from there, you helped cancel out a lot of options that I didn't need/want and pointed me in a direction so I am going to mark this as the answer

Comment: When you clone the git repository from  github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-php.git you can go into 1-hello-world and just run `gcloud app deploy`, all the configuration is in the app.yaml file already.

https://cloud.google.com/php/getting-started/hello-world